# nextjs with next-intl is static or dynamic?

Tags: next.js, dynamic, static, web-hosting, next-intl

I finished a website for a client and now she wants me to help to host the website and create a domain, I used in this project **Nextjs 14.0 and Next-intl** for translation, here's the structure of my code:

[My folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01XUB.png)

I intend to use hostinger for that but I never created a domain and I don't know how it works right, should I use *VPS* or the normal ones?

** I've been searching in many sources such as ChatGPT, Stack overflow and many other sites. The things i'd saw was like "if you use static code so host your site like that" or "if you use dynamic code host your site like that" but I don't know if my code is static or dynamic **

Comment: Do you want to use server side rendering or is your client happy with only client side rendering (and the SEO implications) of that?

Comment: next-intl depends on a middleware to detect the locale, which requires server

Comment: My client is fine with client side rendering, since it's a single page